# Add custom image to Marker Cluster without overwriting markers

Tags: jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have the following jQuery code which adds map marker clusters:

```
markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map);
```

I'm using `markerCluster.addMarker(Marker);` to add individual markers to clusters (full code block at the bottom of the page).

The problem I have is my clusters have no image attached by default.

I can do the following:

```
var options = 'an image path';
markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map,markers,options);
```

However as options is the third parameter, I effectively overwrite the second parameter. Is there a way to set an image to MarkerCluster without overwriting the markers?

```
(function () {
            var address = response[key]["address"];
            $.getJSON('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='+response[key]["post_code"]+'&sensor=false', null, function (data) {
                var p = data.results[0].geometry.location
                var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(p.lat, p.lng);
                var Marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: latlng,
                    map: map,
                    content: address
                });
                markerCluster.addMarker(Marker);
                google.maps.event.addListener(Marker, 'click', function () {    
                    infowindow.setContent(this.content);
                    infowindow.open(map, this);
                });
            });
        })();
```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.  How are you creating the `markerCluster`?  You should be able to create it before you add any markers with an empty array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, `MarkerClusterer` looks for markers in the `../images` folder (relative to the position of `markerclusterer.js`).

The easiest thing for you would be to get the image folder from the [github](https://github.com/googlemaps/js-marker-clusterer), so the structure of your files is following:

```
-images
  -m1.png
  -m2.png
  -..etc other files from the directory
-SOME_FOLDER //can be lib, libraries, what have you
  -markerclusterer.js
```

Alternatively you can play with `imagePath` attribute of the `options` object, so you would have something like this:

```
var options = { imagePath: "PATH_TO_IMAGES_FOLDER/m" };
markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, options);
```