# Upgrading bootstrap version - twitter-bootstrap-rails

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap gem in my project.

```
gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails'
```

The bootstrap version that i have now is

```
/*! normalize.css v3.0.1 | MIT License | git.io/normalize */
```

I need to upgrade to latest bootstrap version.

It seems like the bootstrap version is not updated in the gem (https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails/blob/master/app/assets/stylesheets/twitter-bootstrap-static/bootstrap.css.erb).

How can i upgrade the version in my application?

Comment: The latest version of Bootstrap is 4.0.0. It will break your layout if you don't manually adjust things because B4 is totally incompatible with B3.

Answer (score 1):

There are several options:

1. You can fork [twitter-bootstrap-rails gem](https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails), update BS to version 4 and edit your `Gemfile`:

   ```
   gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails', git: 'link_to_your_fork'
   ```
2. You can migrate to [bootstrap-rubygem](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-rubygem) gem instead which uses BS4
3. You can download latest version of BS from [official site](https://getbootstrap.com/) and manually put `.js` and `.css` files to `./vendor/assets/` directory. Look at these SO answers for reference: [first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37580325/rails-4-how-to-reference-a-javascript-source-in-vendor-file) and [second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25983283/how-to-load-vendor-asset-folder-in-rails-4)

For options 2 and 3 make sure you dont use helper methods in your code which [twitter-bootstrap-rails gem provides](https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails/tree/master/app/helpers)