# Google map cluster custom image

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, react-google-maps

I would like to change google map clustering with custom image. However, it does not change anything I provide. This initMap function is

> https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/marker-clustering

And I tried to change the cluster image with some random image from google. 
However, it does not render anything.

Cluster does not support custom cluster image  ??

```
function initMap() {

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 3,
          center: {lat: -28.024, lng: 140.887}
        });

        // Create an array of alphabetical characters used to label the markers.
        var labels = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';

        // Add some markers to the map.
        // Note: The code uses the JavaScript Array.prototype.map() method to
        // create an array of markers based on a given "locations" array.
        // The map() method here has nothing to do with the Google Maps API.
        var markers = locations.map(function(location, i) {
          return new google.maps.Marker({
            position: location,
            label: labels[i % labels.length]
          });
        });

        // Add a marker clusterer to manage the markers.
        var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers,
            {imagePath: 'http://www.empowervate.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/circle.jpg'});
      }
```

Thanks for help @henrisycip

I was able to change cluster image by providing styles option which is like below. I am not sure why imagePath does not do anything ..

```
 styles={[
              {
                url: "/static/images/cluster/m1.png",
                height: 53,
                width: 53
              },
              {
                url: "/static/images/cluster/m2.png",
                height: 53,
                width: 53
              },
              {
                url: "/static/images/cluster/m3.png",
                height: 53,
                width: 53
              },
              {
                url: "/static/images/cluster/m4.png",
                height: 53,
                width: 53
              },
              {
                url: "/static/images/cluster/m5.png",
                height: 53,
                width: 53
              }
            ]}
```

Answer (score 8):

There's a specific way those images are loaded and it's because of the markerclusterer.js library that's linked to the sample code.

It will look at the `imagePath` you provided but it will be iterated upon, looking for image1, image2, image3, etc. That's why the default path of `https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/m` works because it will start looking for m1.png, m2.png, m3.png etc.

Here's the part of the library that says it's doing that:

```
'imagePath': (string) The base URL where the images representing
 *                  clusters will be found. The full URL will be:
 *                  {imagePath}[1-5].{imageExtension}
 *                  Default: '../images/m'.
```

Check your console and I'm sure you're getting something like this:

> GET http://www.empowervate.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/circle.jpg1.png 404 (Not Found)

Everything you need to know is actually on the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/marker-clustering#adding-a-marker-clusterer). You'll see that there's an instruction to download a copy of markerclusterer.js, m1.png, m2.png, etc. and just change the paths to your own folder structure.

An example of your image path would be:
`imagePath: 'http://www.empowervate.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/circle'`
provided you have circle1.png, circle2.png, etc.

You can also check this previous question as well: [Add custom image to Marker Cluster without overwriting markers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37469525/add-custom-image-to-marker-cluster-without-overwriting-markers)

Comment: I tried to do imagePath='/static/images/cluster' and added m1,m2,m3....png. However, it does not seems to change image nor throw 404

Comment: Can you edit your post to show a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that way I can help you debug in an isolated example. Also make sure you have 5 images as well.

Comment: I was able to change image by adding styles object. Thanks for help though @henrisycip

Answer (score 2):

Simple solution can be appending image url with question mark.

```
imagePath: '<image_url>?'
```

Another solution can be setting custom styles like

```
  new MarkerClusterer(map, marker, {
    styles: [
      {
        url: '<image_url>'
      }
    ]
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, you can just append '&z=' (z can be what ever parameter name you want) to the end of your image URL and it will allow you to use any image you like.

This will prevent the auto appended '[1|2|3].png' from changing your URL.